# Redirect everything after domain.com/articles.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

So i have this issue, with changing an old site with a new and I need to redirect all the old links. So have this:
**domain.com/articles.php?var=1**
I basicly want to redirect everything after **articles.php** to just **domain.com**, including the **/articles.php**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use: `Redirectmatch ^/(articles\.php)$ http://newdomain.com/$1`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/articles\.php$ /
```

or if you have mod_rewrite rules already in your htaccess file, you need to use mod_rewrite isntead, and add this rule above whatever rules are already there:

```
RewriteRule ^articles\.php$ / [L,R=301]
```